# How do I assign unique document numbers based on a policy nomenclature system?

Tags: document-library, document-id, document-management

I need to create a unique number ID column based on our organization's policy nomenclature system which is set up as "##.##.##", where the first two digits are the department code, the second two are the sub-category code, and the last two are the unique incremental number within that category. For example, Admin is department 01 and has three categories - Leadership (01), Emergency Management (02), and Legal (03); clinical is dept. 02 and has multiple categories - Med Management (01), Infection control (02), and Prov. of Care (03) (see screenshot).
[image: Example Numbering set-up]

So, our Emergency management plan would be numbered "01.02.01", and the evacuation policy would be 01.02.02 since the plan was the first document in that category.
Is there a way to automate number assignments in a sharepoint document libraries so authors don't need to manually determine the number? I currently have 2 choice columns in the document library - one for department and one for category, but don't know how to automatically convert those labels into there corresponding code and get an incremental number for the category.

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible.
First you need to create increment counter SharePoint list so you can know what is the next incremental number (this way you can support multiple libraries with same counter)

Then you need a Flow to trigger when the item is created. Figure out what is the first 4 numbers (if else) and then read what would be next increment, Update the file and the counter table.